# updating data using get method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling, sql-update

it seems like I can't update my table

I'm using href like this:

```
href="data/updatefunction.php?updtch=0&teachid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&classid=<?php echo $classid;?>"
```

and the data goes here:

**updatefunction.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['updtch'])){
    global $con;
    $teachid = $_GET['teachid'];
    $classid = $_GET['classid'];

    $q = $con->query("UPDATE class SET teacher=$teachid WHERE id=$classid");
```

I echoed my `teachid` and `classid` they transferred without problem

mysqli error is nothing, I get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingsystem\admin\data\updatefunction.php:8 
>   
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingsystem\admin\data\updatefunction.php on line 8

Comment: Please pay more attention to how you name things. This will make your code much erasier to read. For example: `updtch` should be `updateTeacher` and `teachid` should be `teacherId`. Consistency is also important. In your query you have `teacher=$teachid`. I would have used `teacherId` in the database, it is an id after all. See also: [Ten tips to help you choose good names](http://carlosschults.net/en/how-to-choose-good-names/).

Comment: You _updatefunction.php_ is missing a `}` at the end, although I don't think that's your problem. Do you get an error message? What happens?

Comment: nope its there, im getting error in query

Comment: What error does the query give you? See: [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: mysqli error is nothing, i get this: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingsystem\admin\data\updatefunction.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gradingsystem\admin\data\updatefunction.php on line 8

Comment: Ah, so `$con` is not defined.

Comment: Please go _research_ that error message, it gets asked about all the time. There are plenty of explanations of what it means, and what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: con is not defined, i thought global $con is already working since it works in other codes

Answer (score 0):

In your database , data type of teacher is a string or int ?

if data type of teacher is string than you have to pass $teachid as string like

```
UPDATE class SET teacher = '$teachid' WHERE id = $classid
```

Comment: Ah, this is exactly why good names are needed: `$teachid` suggests it is an integer, but `teacher` suggests it is a string.

Comment: what is $con here ?

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

Comment: If you give an answer where you put user input in a query, it would be wise to point out the dangers of [SQL-injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: this will work :
 
`$query = "UPDATE class SET teacher = '$teachid' WHERE id = $classid";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($result) {
   // your code here
} else {
   // your code here
}`

Comment: Not if `$con` is NULL.